# Serializing derived class to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to serialize a derived class and serialize both the derived's properties and the base's properties. Right now derived properties are serialized, but base properties are not. What am I missing? Both the base and derived types are marked [Serializable].

```
String SaveBody<T>(String bodyFile, T body) where T : FreeBody
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (TextWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(xmlStream))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(fileStream, body);
        fileStream.Flush();
        xmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        String text = new StreamReader(xmlStream).ReadToEnd();
        File.WriteAllText(bodyFile, text);
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken in the problem. The properties not being serialized had been null/empty, so the serializer didn't output them. Initializing those properties to defaults created the behavior I expected.